# Using Filter-Argument in Sum-Expression

Tags: qgis-3, field-calculator, expression, filter, summarizing

I am a QGIS-Newbie who is trying to get familiar with the Field-Calculator.

I want to sum up the `"Length"` of all objects with `"Calc-ID"` of value `1`.

I know it is possible to select all needed objects and calculate the sum by the "Basic Statistics for Fields"-Vector Analysis Tool, but I am still wondering why the formulated Expression is not working and why the Preview tells me the the total sum is `0`.

[image: The total sum should be something around 6000 but not 0.]

Comment: The expression used is correct, there will probably be a problem in the data.

Comment: can you share the dataset?